# JavaFX SetOnCloseRequest() closing all screens

Tags: java, javafx

In my application I have multiple .fxml files. When I set a screen in my application, I also set the `SetOnCloseRequest()` method. For some screens is the code in that method just to switch to another screen. For example: When I have my `Create Bank` screen open and I press the close button, I want to switch back to my `Manage Banks` screen. But when I press the close button, it seems to switch the screens correctly, but very shortly after it closes the `Manage Banks` screen for some reason and the application dont stops running. So I cant do anything after that, because I don't have any GUI.
Does someone knows how to make sure that the `Manage Banks` screens does not close?

Here is my main class with the`SetOnCloseRequest()` method:

```
public class ClientMain extends Application {
    public static String screenCreateBankId = "createBank";
    public static String screenCreateBankFile = "Screens/createBank.fxml";
    public static String screenCreateBankAccountId = "createBankAccount";
    public static String screenCreateBankAccountFile = "Screens/createBankAccount.fxml";
    public static String screenLoginId = "login";
    public static String screenLoginFile = "Screens/login.fxml";
    public static String screenManageBanksId = "manageBanks";
    public static String screenManageBanksFile = "Screens/manageBanks.fxml";
    private static Stage primaryStage;
    private static ScreensController mainContainer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ClientMain.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        mainContainer = new ScreensController();
        mainContainer.loadScreen(ClientMain.screenCreateBankId, ClientMain.screenCreateBankFile);
        mainContainer.loadScreen(ClientMain.screenLoginId, ClientMain.screenLoginFile);
        mainContainer.loadScreen(ClientMain.screenManageBanksId, ClientMain.screenManageBanksFile);

        mainContainer.setScreen(ClientMain.screenLoginId);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void setProperties(String name){
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        switch (name){   
            case "createBank":
                primaryStage.setTitle("Create Bank");
                primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> mainContainer.setScreen(screenManageBanksId));
                break;
            case "login":
                primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
                primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> System.exit(0));
                break;
            case "manageBanks":
                primaryStage.setTitle("Manage Banks");
                primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> mainContainer.getManageBanksController().logoutAdmin());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `ScreensController` class:

```
public class ScreensController extends StackPane {

    private HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();
    private Client client;
    private NewTransactionController newTransactionController;
    private BankAccountController bankAccountController;
    private ManageBanksController manageBanksController;

    public Client getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }

    public NewTransactionController getNewTransactionController() {
        return this.newTransactionController;
    }

    public BankAccountController getBankAccountController() {
        return this.bankAccountController;
    }

    public ManageBanksController getManageBanksController() {
        return this.manageBanksController;
    }

    public ScreensController() {
        try {
            this.client = new Client();
            System.out.println("Client: Client created");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("Client: Cannot create Client");
            System.out.println("Client: RemoteException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void addScreen(String name, Node screen) {
        screens.put(name, screen);
    }

    public void loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            Parent loadScreen = myLoader.load();
            IControllers myScreenController = myLoader.getController();
            if (myScreenController instanceof NewTransactionController) {
                this.newTransactionController = (NewTransactionController) myScreenController;
            } else if (myScreenController instanceof BankAccountController) {
                this.bankAccountController = (BankAccountController) myScreenController;
            } else if (myScreenController instanceof ManageBanksController) {
                this.manageBanksController = (ManageBanksController) myScreenController;
            }
            myScreenController.setScreenParent(this);
            addScreen(name, loadScreen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setScreen(final String name) {
        if (screens.get(name) != null) {
            if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                getChildren().remove(0);
                getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));
                ClientMain.setProperties(name);
            } else {
                //First time start up
                getChildren().add(screens.get(name));
                ClientMain.setProperties(name);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Screen hasn't been loaded!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    event.consume();
    mainContainer.setScreen(screenManageBanksId);
});

...

primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    event.consume();
    mainContainer.getManageBanksController().logoutAdmin();
});
```